# Offer more help to authors of bad edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I recently made the switch from just answering to also trying to improve other's questions and answers.  Apparently, I didn't get the hang of it yet, as half of my edits have been rejected (and some were accepted only by a 3-to-2 vote).  It is clear that I have to improve my editing fu.

The problem I see is that currently, the page encourages learning-by-doing.  This seems wasteful on both my and the reviewers' time.  Getting more information on why an edit was rejected isn't easy.  Learning why an edit was not up to the site's standards isn't as simple as I imagine it could be.  The help section, e.g., doesn't offer any quick to find insights on the usual reasons for rejection.  I did find some very good resources (e.g. the community FAQ, or [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/2425163)), but only after I invested a lot of time into digging through various meta posts.

To summarize the question/suggestion: Should suggested edit rejection notices contain a link to a helpful resource like the community FAQ?  Would it make sense to put those into the user's inbox?

Edit: Example of my thought process while editing

I hope this gives a good insight into the rationale for this request:

- see a [decent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31177564/1) to a question. Notice that it won't work reliably for all users and inputs.
- edit answer to make the restrictions more obvious to future readers, fix restriction were possible
- edit gets rejected, reason: "addresses author, should be a comment"
- *"Okay, so I should not assume that the author was aware of the restrictions and must be informed via comment.  But surely, nobody here wants incorrect code, I better just fix that."*
- edit gets rejected again, same reason.
- *confused*
- search the help center and meta for hints, finding nothing substantial.
- follow suggestion, write comment about the incorrect code. The question author asks to fix it in the code, answer that I couldn't edit the code.  After a while, answer author makes the edit I was proposing.
- *"WTF? Why did that have to be so complicated?"*
- search meta again; finding nothing.
- tempted to give up editing all together.
- search meta some more, finally finding the [reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/2425163) for the rejections (don't edit code unless you follow some specific rules).
- *"Aha, so that's why!  Yeah, I can see now why this makes sense."*

The whole thing is obvious in retrospect, but linking some resources from within the rejection notice would have shortened the above process considerably (and would have saved some poor reviewers' time).

Granted, I'm not a smart man.  But I'm here to learn and improve, so please don't make it difficult for people like me to become better editors.

Comment: Not sure if your asking for actual reasons your edits were rejected or not, but [your](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8361863) [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8652393) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8652743) all seem to be suggesting changes to code -- this is generally not the done thing. If you want to suggest these, you should comment instead.

Comment: @TZHX I think the OP realized that (after searching and finding the answer).  I think this is more of a request to make the information easier to find, at the very least by providing links.

Comment: The reviewers have to pick a reason when they reject your edit.  That's supposed to be helpful to you, unclear why it isn't.  "It should have been written as a comment or an answer" doesn't leave much to guess at, maybe you should explicitly ask if you don't know what that means.

Comment: The rejection reasons are helpful, but only for that specific edit.  It tells me which rule I broke, but leaves me guessing what the rule really says in it's entirety.  It's kind of like being told "you were speeding, you must slow down" while driving, but not telling you that there is a concept known as "speed limit".  Without understanding the underlying rules (traffic regulations in this flawed analogy), one is more likely to repeat the same error again in a different situation.

Comment: +1. this would also benefit me and perhaps others who have earned enough reputation to `sudo edit post` but haven't necessarily actually learned how to edit. You can get enough rep form answers & questions to skip the edit review process without ever having an edit approved.